# No Workflow/WCF templates in Visual Studio Community Edition 2019

Tags: visual-studio, wcf, workflow-foundation

I am using Visual Studio Community Edition 2019.
When creating a new project I did not see any WorkFlow templates.
Clicked to "install more tools and features" at the bottom of the screen as people recommended in this case,  and then "Individual components" tab to check if they are available for installation, but was not able to find any Workflow templates.  I am running into the same issue when trying to find any WCF related templates.
Please point me to the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WCF and Workflow project template locates in Individual component in the Visual Studio Installer.
Please refer to the below steps.
1.  Open the Visual Studio installer.
[image]
2.  Tick the corresponding options.
[image]
3. Check the project template in Visual Studio.
[image]
Feel Free to let me know if the problem still exists.